Can we create multiple versions of 2nd Generation Managed Application which is listed on AppExchange and share with customers?
We have created a 2nd generation managed package (Paid Application), which has been published on the AppExchange after successfully passing the Salesforce security review.
Now, our requirement is to create multiple versions of the package as per our customer's needs, with each version offering different features. For example, version 1.6 is currently published on the AppExchange, and we have created two new versions, 1.7 and 1.8. These two new versions of the package will be built on top of 1.6 version of the package.
Also, these new versions might or might not contain the base features of 1.6 version of the Managed package.
We would like to confirm the following:

As the second generation managed package works, it provide the flexibility to create multiple packages with the same namespace( where we can have a base(Parent) package and then add-on packages with additional feature or updates in the base package(like a Child Package)). Can we develop these packages and provide it to the customer as a AppExchange Solution?

If a user wants to access version 1.6, will they still be able to install it even though version 1.8 is the latest version?

Let’s say we keep version 1.6 on the AppExchange and create two new versions, 1.7 and 1.8, which we distribute directly to customers by manually sharing the link. What all information do we need to share with Salesforce and what will be the process?


Can anyone please provide insights on above questions. Thanks in advance.
